# fill form automatically

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create c# code to go to site, fill in form submit record.

I have tried using seleniumhq but this creates tests..I need more of a script i can run once to help me register some users for my site

any ideas??

Comment: Is this one of your own sites or a third party site?

Comment: this is my site, i want a function on my web app

Comment: If you have a service that is running behind the scenes you can skip the UI automation. Just use this service instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create c# code that posts data to the form page for the site that you are trying to register the people for. Otherwise depending on the browser you could use something like iMacros to automate the form filling. The other answers are also correct. Unless it is a site you control none of these methods will work if the site uses captcha or other methods to prevent automatic form filling.

Edit: Something like http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx would be a good start.

Comment: ok thanks this is perfect..when i post is there way i can get auth code from the page that i post to?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by auth code? Is there some sort of authorization that your registration pages are doing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to automate mouse clicks and keyboard strokes, you can try [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml).

Comment: i need a c# code basically i need function that i can run to fill in this form

Answer (score 0):

i would use an HttpWebRequest Object to submit the form, a quick google found this:

http://netomatix.com/HttpPostData.aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://watin.sourceforge.net

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I prefer to remain brief when possible regardless of down votes. The question here is not about understanding a concept. He is just looking for a out of box solution for his problem.